# CoreData NSPredicate error NSInvalidArgumentException after converting iPhone app to xcode 4.5.2 iOS6 with ARC

Tags: core-data, ios6, nsdate

This is my first question at stackoverflow. This community has been very helpful to me, it provided lots of solutions for my iPhone app developing. However, I ran into an issue this week and have spent two days on it without any progress. I'm posting the question here and hopefully can get fixed with you guys' help.

I'm using coredata and there's two tables, Prayers and Schedules, have a many-to-many relationship. I want to get a list of prayers that are scheduled for today. Here's my code:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    unsigned units = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; 
    [gregorian setFirstWeekday:1];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [gregorian components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // Get necessary date components
    [comps setHour:0];
    [comps setMinute:0];
    [comps setSecond:1];

    //get beginning of today
    NSDate *startOfToday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
    //get the beginning of tomorrow
    [comps setDay:[comps day] + 1];
    NSDate *endOfDay = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@", startOfToday,endOfDay);

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (schedules.nextEventDateTime >= %@ AND schedules.nextEventDateTime < %@) AND prayerType == 0 AND finished == YES AND answered == NO", startOfToday, endOfDay];

    [request setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

This piece of code used to work fine before I upgrade to xcode 4.5.2 and ARC. After I converted the app to ARC with xcode 4.5.2. I got an error(crash) on the following line when running the app (everything else seems fine):

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (schedules.nextEventDateTime >= %@ AND schedules.nextEventDateTime < %@) AND prayerType == 0 AND finished == YES AND answered == NO", startOfToday, endOfDay];
```

The console output and error is:

```
     2013-03-15 23:41:36.763 WePrayers[12121:c07] 2013-03-15 04:00:01 +0000 2013-03-16 04:00:01 +0000

     2013-03-15 23:41:37.837 WePrayers[12121:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY (schedules.nextEventDateTime >= %@ AND schedules.nextEventDateTime < %@) AND prayerType == 0 AND finished == YES AND answered == NO"'
     *** First throw call stack:
     (0x29f2012 0x20ebe7e 0x1abc25 0x1aba43 0x1ab9f7 0x19ce5 0x186fb 0x61e8d5 0x61eb3d 0x190e83 0x29b1376 0x29b0e06 0x2998a82 0x2997f44 0x2997e1b 0x2f207e3 0x2f20668 0x56f65c 0x2ecd 0x2e05)
     libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I tried to change the line to the following and it worked without any issue:

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY schedules.nextEventDateTime >= %@ AND prayerType == 0 AND finished == YES AND answered == NO", startOfToday];
```

However, I need to compare the schedules.nextEventDateTime >= startOfToday and < endOfDay to get the schedules that are schedule for Today only.

If I change the line to the following (remove the parenthis)

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY schedules.nextEventDateTime >= %@ AND schedules.nextEventDateTime < %@ AND prayerType == 0 AND finished == YES AND answered == NO", startOfToday, endOfDay];
```

It will run pass this line but fail on the line :
        NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Error is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Could anyone know what's wrong with my code? Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Hey @Joe does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in you case `SUBQUERY` may help you.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"prayerType == 0 AND finished == YES AND answered == NO AND SUBQUERY(schedules, $sub, $sub.nextEventDateTime >= %@ AND $sub.nextEventDateTime <  %@).@count > 0", startOfToday, endOfDay];
```

And pay attention to expressions order. In general, joins (queries that cross relationships) are also expensive operations, and you should avoid them if you can. Avoids making a join unless the first test succeeds.

Comment: Mark, Thank you so much. The solution you provided worked very well.